# jQuery not extracting text values clicked properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a php script to extract values from the database as follows,

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
    <?php       
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM upperbit_categories";                       
        $rslt = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);
        while ($output = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt)) {
    ?>
    <li class="nav" id="test" style= "text-decoration: none;">
        <a href="postad" >
            <?php echo $output['Classify'].'<br/>'; } ?>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" id="testing">
</div>
```

this code gives me below result:

> General equipment
>
> Test equipment
>
> Renewable energy
>
> Engineering Services
>
> Trade services

Below is the jQuery bit:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test").click(function(){
            var classprod = $(this).text();
            $("#testing").text(classprod);
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    });
</script>
```

However this only outputs line-1 but nothing else i.e. *General equipment*. 
What changes do I have to make to my javascript code in order to be able to display any item clicked?

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context and BTW a LI shouldn't be direct child of a DIV element

Comment: I formatted your code. You should now be able to see what's wrong by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General, id of HTML elements should be unique, this requirements can be realized when using jQuery or JavaScript. In your code, you used `id="test"` for the `li` element inside a loop, and then you referenced to them using `$("#test")` then, only first `li` works due to uniqueness of id.

you can use class instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

Little errors, but easy to solve. Your php loop leave a lot of tags opened, an closes just one, then you should use a **Class** instead on an **Id** for multiple elements.
Another tip is that you should open and close the **ul** tag before your list.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
    <ul>
        <?php        
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM upperbit_categories";                       
        $rslt = mysqli_query($dbc,$qry);
        while($output = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt)){?>
            <li class="nav test" style= "text-decoration: none;"><a href="postad" ><?php echo $output['Classify'];?></a></li>
        <?php };?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="testing"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test").on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var classprod = $(this).text();
            $("#testing").text(classprod);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Also, I don't know what you're doing, but consider to use **$(".test a")** instead of **$(".test")**